# Best Methods to Insure Vintage Gear

Tags: insurance

I enjoy collecting and using vintage photo gear. A lot of the pieces that I own are hardly anything to write home about (from a financial perspective), such as my Canon SII or Yashica 44.

But, finding replacements in similar condition is tough now and will likely become harder over time. (They may or may not appreciate in value, so the coverage would have to cover either circumstance)

What is the best way (service or combo of services) to insure the gear so that, should anything ever happen to it, the gear is replaced at the current market value? (current being sometime in the future when the replacement is in need)

I'm personally in the USA and looking for advice for within the States - though any information would be helpful as, I believe, insurance should be comparable between countries. At the least, it'll give me a good place to start.

Comment: Country could be useful (I could provide info for the UK for example, but would probably not be relevant to any other country)

Comment: @CrazyDino, USA added to the Q. I'd still love to know more about options in the UK to see if I can find anything similar here. It's difficult relaying to an insurance that I have a camera that cost me $700 but whose estimated value is $1200 but which *may* be sold at almost any value up to $3000 in the future.

Comment: in that case do you want to adjust your final line to your question saying other countries maybe valid for comparisson?

Comment: @CrazyDino, good call.

Comment: Done. My last paragraph should be relevant to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, there are some insurers providing dedicated camera/photographer insurance. The cost per month is depending on the cover, e.g. if it includes mechanical breakdown and in vehicle insurance and the total value of the gear. It can also cover other useful things photographers may need such as public liability and indemnity insurance.

We also have home contents insurance (insurance against your posessions and property fittings) and usually posessions up to a certain value (say £1000) are automatically covered but anything more then this will have to be stipulated with the insurer (so I have Super Duper Camera 3000, value of £3000, this is the serial number, here is a picture against dated newspaper that I own it). Again, this will have implications on excess and insurance premiums.

Regardless of your choice and location I suggest getting your gear valued (take it into a dealer who sells second hand gear and ask for a valuation for insurance purposes is what I would do) and keeping hold of the valuation as proof of ownership, on top of any invoices/receipts of purchase.